# UITextField is bigger in Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

I'm having issues with my app design,

I have a Textfield on my view, and I positioned it and sized it (by dragging the element) to how I want it:

[image]

but when I view it in the simulator, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it is bigger and unsightly. It goes right to the edge. How do I make sure that it will look the same across all iOS Devices and in the Simulator?

Bi of a noob here so hoping for a detailed answer.

Thanks.

P.s I'm using swift if there is any code requirements.

Comment: Are you using auto layout or fixing frames by yourself?

Comment: Fixing by myself. Not done anything with Auto Layout

Comment: Can you add the code where you are setting frame for the textfield?

Comment: There is no code,storyboard was used

Answer (score 1):

Use auto layout. Auto layout is a way to add constraints to your UI allowing for you to fix problems like yours and allows for your to have a similar UI across multiple screen sizes with relative ease.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` try setting width of your textfield manually depending on the width of your screen. Try this out

```
var newFrame = textField.frame
newFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 50 //change 50 according to your needs
newFrame.origin.x = 25 //should be half of constant set above so that textfield is in centre
textField.frame = newFrame
```